# Map items onto a grid

Tags: javascript, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have an array of objects. Each object contains 3 images, a name and detail. I'm trying to map those objects onto a bootstrap card but each card is getting rendered on a separate line. I want the cards to form a grid. 3 cards in one row and the rest on the following line.

```
const data = [
    nikeItem1,
    nikeItem2,
    adidasItem1,
    adidasItem2,
    reebokItem1,
    reebokItem2,
    uaItem1,
    uaItem2,
  ];
{data.map((item, i) => {
        const img = item ? item.img1 : null;
        const heading = item ? item.name : null;
        const desc = item ? item.detail : null;
        return (
            <div className="card " style={{ width: "18rem" }}>
              <img src={img} className="card-img-top" />
              <div className="card-body">
                <h5 className="card-title">{heading}</h5>
                <p className="card-text">{desc}</p>
              </div>
            </div>
        );
      })}
```

Everything is needed to be created from bootstrap.

Comment: The CSS you are using would be helpful to answer this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a row as a main container, `className=row` and then inside of it, add another div with `className="col-4"` and then add the card inside of it

Row > Col-4 > Card

For demo visit: https://codepen.io/theredcap/pen/GRZoGQQ

I don't know much about React, but this is how you do it using Bootstrap, this should work given that you are returning the html.